# Django: How to get value in one model from the other model?

Tags: python, django, oop

It feels like a very simple question, but how to get value in one model from the other one in django?

I have my `models.py` like this:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='Patient ID')

class Salvage_Treatment(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Salvage_treatment_end_date = models.DateField()

class Survival_Parameters(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    salv_treat = models.ForeignKey(Salvage_Treatment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    salvage_treatment_end_date = models.DateField()
    id_patient = models.ForeignKey('Patient', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Let's assume that I have a patient with `id_patient = 2` and I fullfiled the `Salvage_Treatment` form for him with `id=1` (id of this form) and some date in `Salvage_treatment_end_date`. Now I need to have this same date to be put automatically in `Survival_Parameters.salvage_treatment_end_date`. How can I do that? I don't want to choose which `Salvage_Treatment` form to get the data from - instead I **ONLY** want to select the patient's ID.

Comment: This question isn't sufficiently specifying what you are trying to accomplish. Do you have a Form and a View? If so, show them (or the relevant parts thereof)

Comment: It's against Django conventions to call a ForeignKey `something_id`. Just call it `something`. Not least because the suffix `_id` is "magic" in Django, and `something_id_id` is extremely confusing!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which of the following three is the query you asking for

```
salvage_treatment_end_date = Salvage_Treatment.objects.filter(id_patient=patient_id_you_have).values(‘Salvage_treatment_end_date’)
salvage_treatment_end_date = Survival_Parameters.objects.filter(id_patient=patient_id_you_have).values(‘salvage_treatment_end_date’)
salvage_treatment_end_date = Survival_Parameters.objects.filter(salv_treat__id_patient=patient_id_you_have).values(‘salvage_treatment_end_date’)
```

The .filter method restrict queryset by the patient’s id you have, and the .values method restrict output to a single field.

Note the double _ after salv_treat in the third query, that’s django’s way of referring relational field.

I could agree no more with @nigel222, even if you use id_patient instead of patient_id. When you access salvage_treatment.patient_id and it actually returns a Patient instance, it strongly hurts readability.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this approach. As I understand, I should use your code in `views.py` right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

as i assume you don't want to set default value of current date of `salvage_treatment_end_date` for `Survival_Parameters`
`default=datetime.now`

but in your case you can overwrite `save()` method of `Survival_Parameters`
and here you can save date of `Salvage_treatment_end_date` in you `salvage_treatment_end_date` just like this

```
class Patient(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='Patient ID')

class Salvage_Treatment(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Salvage_treatment_end_date = models.DateField()

class Survival_Parameters(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    salv_treat = models.ForeignKey(Salvage_Treatment, 
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    salvage_treatment_end_date = models.DateField()
    id_patient = models.ForeignKey('Patient', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        self.salvage_treatment_end_date = 
self.salv_treat.Salvage_treatment_end_date
        super().save(**kwargs)
```

becasue of the relation (one to many) between these two table you can access the `Salvage_Treatment` with `self.salv_treat` and also access the `Salvage_treatment_end_date` with `self.salv_treat.Salvage_treatment_end_date`
after all you call the call `super` class `save()` method

Comment: Firstly I also thought that it would work out, I tried it this way, but without result ... The problem here is that the Django has to know which date of many dates stored in `Salvage_Treatment` to choose. And this should be related to patient's ID.